# spring .net nhibernate session management for console application

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spring.net, spring-data

I understand that spring can manage your sessions for you, if configured like so:

```xml
<object name="SessionFactory"
                    type="MyApp.DAL.DAOs.SessionFactoryObject, Leverate.Crm.CrmService.DAL">
<!--My class which inherits from LocalSessionFactoryObject and defines the mapping assemblies to be used--> 

    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
      <dictionary>
        <entry key="cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <entry key="command_timeout" value="180"/>
        <entry key="connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
        <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect"/>
        <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>

      </dictionary>
    </property>
    <property name="SchemaUpdate" value="false"/>
  </object>

    <db:provider id="DbProvider"
                   provider="SqlServer-1.1"
                   connectionString="Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=northwind;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
```

problem is, that using `SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()` throws a `'No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here'` exception.

I saw some answers saying that in web context you have to use `openSessionInView` (or some such) httpModule. But what do you do in a console app (or windows service, for that matter)?

Comment: it is a console application,then it is a single user app.Why you want to share sessions?

Comment: firstly- I might have several operations / threads that I want to share the same session for. Secondly- I was under the impression (correct me if i'm wrong) that I can use spring purely for convenience, and save myself calls to `SessionFactory.OpenSession()`

Comment: if you are just using spring.net for session management.I suggest using Ninject

Comment: Why do you suggest using Ninject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exposing your session factory as a transaction aware session factory, which implies sessions are managed for you by Spring for all Methods that are correctly wrapped in a transaction. For wrapping your data access methods in a transaction with spring, you can use a [declarative (attribute driven)](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-declarative) or [programmatic](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-tx-programmatic) approach.

Comment: that's correct. I might further add that I find it completely acceptable to call `SessionFactory.OpenSession()` in my app's code. I just have to maange the sessions myself (not such a hard task, anyway)